How to efficiently remove overlapping circles from the dataset
I have a dataset of about 20,000 records that represent global cities of population > 20,000. I have estimated radius which more or less describes the size of the city. It's not exactly accurate but for my purposes it will be enough.
that I'm loading it into my Panda dataframe object. Below is the sample
name_city,country_code,latitude,longitude,geohash,estimated_radius,population
Vitry-sur-Seine,FR,48.78716,2.40332,u09tw9qjc3v3,1000,81001
Vincennes,FR,48.8486,2.43769,u09tzkx5dr13,500,45923
Villeneuve-Saint-Georges,FR,48.73219,2.44925,u09tpxrmxdth,500,30881
Villejuif,FR,48.7939,2.35992,u09ttdwmn45z,500,48048
Vigneux-sur-Seine,FR,48.70291,2.41357,u09tnfje022n,500,26692
Versailles,FR,48.80359,2.13424,u09t8s6je2sd,1000,85416
Vélizy-Villacoublay,FR,48.78198,2.19395,u09t9bmxdspt,500,21741
Vanves,FR,48.82345,2.29025,u09tu059nwwp,500,26068
Thiais,FR,48.76496,2.3961,u09tqt2u3pmt,500,29724
Sèvres,FR,48.82292,2.21757,u09tdryy15un,500,23724
Sceaux,FR,48.77644,2.29026,u09tkp7xqgmw,500,21511
Saint-Mandé,FR,48.83864,2.41579,u09tyfz1eyre,500,21261
Saint-Cloud,FR,48.84598,2.20289,u09tfhhh7n9u,500,28839
Paris,FR,48.85341,2.3488,u09tvmqrep8n,12000,2138551
Orly,FR,48.74792,2.39253,u09tq6q1jyzt,500,20528
Montrouge,FR,48.8162,2.31393,u09tswsyyrpr,500,38708
Montreuil,FR,48.86415,2.44322,u09tzx7n71ub,2000,111240
Montgeron,FR,48.70543,2.45039,u09tpf83dnpn,500,22843
Meudon,FR,48.81381,2.235,u09tdy73p38y,500,44652
Massy,FR,48.72692,2.28301,u09t5yqqvupx,500,38768
Malakoff,FR,48.81999,2.29998,u09tsr6v13tr,500,29420
Maisons-Alfort,FR,48.81171,2.43945,u09txtbkg61z,1000,53964
Longjumeau,FR,48.69307,2.29431,u09th0q9tq1s,500,20771
Le Plessis-Robinson,FR,48.78889,2.27078,u09te9txch23,500,22510
Le Kremlin-Bicêtre,FR,48.81471,2.36073,u09ttwrn2crz,500,27867
Le Chesnay,FR,48.8222,2.12213,u09t8rc3cjwz,500,29154
La Celle-Saint-Cloud,FR,48.85029,2.14523,u09tbufje6p6,500,21539
Ivry-sur-Seine,FR,48.81568,2.38487,u09twq8egqrc,1000,57897
Issy-les-Moulineaux,FR,48.82104,2.27718,u09tezd5njkr,1000,61447
Fresnes,FR,48.75568,2.32241,u09tkgenkj6r,500,24803
Fontenay-aux-Roses,FR,48.79325,2.29275,u09ts4t92cn3,500,24680
Clamart,FR,48.80299,2.26692,u09tes6dp0dn,1000,51400
Choisy-le-Roi,FR,48.76846,2.41874,u09trn12bez7,500,35590
Chevilly-Larue,FR,48.76476,2.3503,u09tmmr7mfns,500,20125
Châtillon,FR,48.8024,2.29346,u09tshnn96xx,500,32383
Châtenay-Malabry,FR,48.76507,2.26655,u09t7t6mn7yj,500,32715
Charenton-le-Pont,FR,48.82209,2.41217,u09twzu3r9hq,500,30910
Cachan,FR,48.79632,2.33661,u09tt5j7nvqd,500,26540
Bagnolet,FR,48.86667,2.41667,u09tyzzubrxb,500,33504
Bagneux,FR,48.79565,2.30796,u09tsdbx727w,500,38900
Athis-Mons,FR,48.70522,2.39147,u09tn6t2mr16,500,31225
Alfortville,FR,48.80575,2.4204,u09txhf6p7jp,500,37290
Quinze-Vingts,FR,48.84656,2.37439,u09tyh0zz6c8,500,26265
Croulebarbe,FR,48.81003,2.35403,u09tttd5hc5f,500,20062
Gare,FR,48.83337,2.37513,u09ty1cdbxcq,1000,75580
Maison Blanche,FR,48.82586,2.3508,u09tv2rz1xgx,1000,64302


Below is the visual representation of the data sample:

My goal is to find an efficient algorithm that would remove the intersecting circles and only keep the one with largest population.
My initial approach was to determine which circles are intersecting using haversine formula. Problem was that to check every record for intersections with others, it needs to traverse entire dataset. The time complexity of this was too high.
My second approach was to segregate the dataset by country code, and run the comparisons by chunks:
  def _remove_intersecting_circles_for_country(df_country):
    """Helper function to remove intersections within a single country."""
    indices_to_remove = set()
    for i in range(len(df_country)):
      for j in range(i + 1, len(df_country)):
        distance = haversine(df_country['latitude'].iloc[i], df_country['longitude'].iloc[i],
                            df_country['latitude'].iloc[j], df_country['longitude'].iloc[j])
        if distance < df_country['estimated_radius'].iloc[i] + df_country['estimated_radius'].iloc[j]:
          if df_country['population'].iloc[i] < df_country['population'].iloc[j]:
            indices_to_remove.add(df_country.index[i]) 
          else:
            indices_to_remove.add(df_country.index[j])
    return indices_to_remove

  all_indices_to_remove = set()
  for country_code in df['country_code'].unique():
    df_country = df[df['country_code'] == country_code]
    indices_to_remove = _remove_intersecting_circles_for_country(df_country)
    all_indices_to_remove.update(indices_to_remove)

  new_df = df.drop(index=all_indices_to_remove)
  return new_df

This has significantly improved the performance because to check every record we only need to check against all the records with the same country_code. But that still makes a lot of unnecessary comparisons

And what happens when there are large cities beside the border in two or more adjacent countries?

In my current implementation where I'm splitting by county it will not remove the overlapping circles because in every iteration it ignores the other countries. For those instances it would be acceptable because there won't be many scenarios like this

Once you have the circles as polygons, determining intersections between polygons is very fast if you use a spatial index to do so.
So, you can:

buffer the points to circles. In WGS84 this would be imprecise, so the buffering needs to be done via a sidestep to an equidistant projection.
calculating which circles intersect can be done very fast using a spatial index. E.g. geopandas.sjoin uses a spatial index under the hood.
now you can determine which circles intersect a circle representing a city with a larger population and remove those.

Result (red: original cities, blue: retained cities):

Code:
from pathlib import Path
import geopandas as gpd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from pyproj import CRS, Transformer
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.ops import transform


def geodesic_point_buffer(lat, lon, distance):
    # Azimuthal equidistant projection
    aeqd_proj = CRS.from_proj4(
        f"+proj=aeqd +lat_0={lat} +lon_0={lon} +x_0=0 +y_0=0")
    tfmr = Transformer.from_proj(aeqd_proj, aeqd_proj.geodetic_crs)
    buf = Point(0, 0).buffer(distance)  # distance in metres
    return transform(tfmr.transform, buf)

# Read the csv file with data
#csv_path = Path(__file__).resolve().with_suffix(".csv")
csv_path = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/theroggy/pysnippets/refs/heads/main/pysnippets/stackoverflow_questions/2024/Q4/2024-10-25_circles.csv"
points_df = gpd.read_file(csv_path, autodetect_type=True)

# Convert the points to circles by buffering them
points_buffer_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    points_df,
    geometry=points_df.apply(
        lambda row : geodesic_point_buffer(row.latitude, row.longitude, row.estimated_radius), axis=1
    ),
    crs=4326,
)

# Determine the intersecting city buffers (result includes self-intersections)
intersecting_gdf = points_buffer_gdf.sjoin(points_buffer_gdf)

# Get all city buffers that intersect a city with a larger population
intersecting_larger_population_df = intersecting_gdf.loc[
    intersecting_gdf.population_left < intersecting_gdf.population_right
]

# Remove the city buffers that intersect with a larger population city buffer
result_gdf = points_buffer_gdf[
    ~points_buffer_gdf.index.isin(intersecting_larger_population_df.index)
]

# Plot result
ax = points_buffer_gdf.boundary.plot(color="red")
result_gdf.boundary.plot(color="blue", ax=ax)
plt.show()


I tried it and it went from ~5 minutes to around ~30 seconds on my machine. Thanks!

From the visual representation, 1st thing that came to mind was to use an image proc approach with outermost contours ( and mapping geo coords to pixel coords). Not sure if suited for very large datasets with very big spacings between cities (but why should one see if Lyon overlaps Paris ?), but on the provided near-Paris samples its times faster than the current solution.
We are in O(n log(n)) + O(n) for time complexity compared with current O(n^2). However the main tradeoff could be the image creation with enough resolution. Its contour processing should be okay-ish considering optimized C++ OpenCV under the hood
import numpy as np
import cv2
import pandas as pd
from typing import Tuple
from io import StringIO

def detect_non_overlapping_circles(df: pd.DataFrame, image_size:Tuple[int, int] = (128, 128)):
    img = np.zeros(image_size, dtype=np.uint8) # Black image

    lat_min, lat_max = df['latitude'].min(), df['latitude'].max()
    lon_min, lon_max = df['longitude'].min(), df['longitude'].max()

    def geo_to_pixel(lat: float, lon: float):
        x = int((lon - lon_min) / (lon_max - lon_min) * (image_size[0] - 100) + 50)
        y = int((lat - lat_min) / (lat_max - lat_min) * (image_size[1] - 100) + 50)
        return (x, y)

    # Convert radius to pixels based on the image size and coordinate range
    def radius_to_pixel(radius_meters: float):
        # Using an approximate conversion factor
        earth_circumference = 40075000  # meters
        meters_per_degree = earth_circumference / 360
        lat_range = lat_max - lat_min
        pixels_per_meter = (image_size[1] - 100) / (lat_range * meters_per_degree)
        return int(radius_meters * pixels_per_meter)

    df_sorted = df.sort_values('population', ascending=False)

    kept_indices = []

    for idx, row in df_sorted.iterrows():
        test_img = img.copy()
    
        # Current circle
        center = geo_to_pixel(row['latitude'], row['longitude'])
        radius = radius_to_pixel(row['estimated_radius'])
    
        # Find outermost contour at each time
        cv2.circle(test_img, center, radius, 255, -1)    
        contours, _ = cv2.findContours(test_img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    
        # If exactly one contour, this circle dont overlap with any one
        if len(contours) == len(kept_indices) + 1:
            kept_indices.append(idx)
            img = test_img  # Update the main image

    return df.loc[kept_indices]

def main(df):
    result_df = detect_non_overlapping_circles(df)
    
    print(f"Original number of cities: {len(df)}")
    print(f"Cities after removing overlaps: {len(result_df)}")
    print(result_df[['name_city', 'population', 'estimated_radius']].to_string())

    return result_df

# Not sure if you're working with csv but from what provided
data = 
"""name_city,country_code,latitude,longitude,geohash,estimated_radius,population
Vitry-sur-Seine,FR,48.78716,2.40332,u09tw9qjc3v3,1000,81001
Vincennes,FR,48.8486,2.43769,u09tzkx5dr13,500,45923
Villeneuve-Saint-Georges,FR,48.73219,2.44925,u09tpxrmxdth,500,30881
Villejuif,FR,48.7939,2.35992,u09ttdwmn45z,500,48048
Vigneux-sur-Seine,FR,48.70291,2.41357,u09tnfje022n,500,26692
""" # ...

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data))
df.dropna()

proc_df = main(df) 

With the provided csv and city spacing it worked well down to (128, 128) in image resolution. On my machine, working on a (1024, 1024) image was still faster in execution time than _remove_intersecting_circles_for_country

Thanks for sharing the snippet. I tested  it on my machine and yes it is a lot faster even with 1024x1024 resolution. However there is some missing data. For example when running it with the provided sample data La Celle-Saint-Cloud and Vélizy-Villacoublay are missing, even though they're not intersecting with any other circles. And when testing it with my full dataset, from the 20,000 records only around 7000 remain. I'm not familiar with this approach so I'll ask is there anything that can be done?

A common way to reduce complexity is to overlay a grid on top of your map. For example, overlay a grid of squares that are 100 miles on a side. Create a data structure that will tell you:

What grid square a city is in (the center of the city)
What cities (again, the center of the city's circle) are located within that grid square

Assuming that no city is larger than 100 miles in radius, a city can only intersect with cities whose centers are:

Within its own grid square
In an adjacent grid square
In the case of large cities, adjacent to an adjacent grid square.

In the illustration below, the grid marked '0' is the grid that contains the city you're currently examining. The only cities it can possibly intersect with are those in grid positions marked with a '1' or a '2'. Again, assuming that your grid size is larger than any individual city's size.
    X X X X X X X
    X 2 2 2 2 2 X
    X 2 1 1 1 2 X
    X 2 1 O 1 2 X
    X 2 1 1 1 2 X
    X 2 2 2 2 2 X
    X X X X X X X        

That greatly reduces the number of cities you have to look at when you're trying to determine overlaps. Instead of 20,000 cities, you'll have ... a dozen? A hundred?
It's a small amount of overhead to build that grid so you can bin your items, but the performance benefit is tremendous.
It might make sense, when you're building that data structure, to include for each grid square not only what cities are centered in it, but also what cities encroach upon it. So if "Smallville" is in the grid square you label, for example, C2, and its circumference encroaches on C3, then C2 should contain an entry that says, in effect, "Smallville is located in C2." C3 has an entry that says, "Smallville encroaches on grid square C3."
That information is pretty easy to compute at runtime when you need it, though. Perhaps keeping it around is unnecessary.
Update
Come to think of it, because you have the lat/lon for each city, you already have most of what you need to build the grid. Make your grid one degree of latitude by one degree of longitude. At the equator that gives you squares approximately 69 miles (111 km) square. That compresses as you near the poles, but shouldn't matter. To determine what grid a city belongs in, you just lop off the decimal portions of your lat/lon and index into the grid. You might need some normalization of the numbers (i.e., converting from -180...180 to 0...360).
Anyway, this lets you reduce the problem to a much more manageable size.
